# How to pass varible as the filename for a download?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Okay, I am trying to have the file be renamed whatever the user wishes to name it. However I have having trouble accomplishing this.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'data:' + data;
a.download = 'customfilename' + '.txt';
a.innerHTML = 'DOWNLOAD FILE';

var container = document.getElementById('downloadrequestedfile');
container.appendChild(a);
```

I have tried

```
a.download = 'customfilename' + '.txt';
to
a.download = 'proposed_file_name' + '.txt';
```

to no avail and also

```
var customfilename = prompt('file name?');
a.download = 'customfilename' + '.txt';
```

I cant not figure out why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the variable in quotes. For example:

```js
const customfilename = prompt('file name?');
console.log(customfilename + '.txt');
```